# visualforce preview is displaying blank page

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page apiVersion="45.0" standardController="Account">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Account"/>
        <apex:form>
             <apex:pageBlock title="{!Account.Name}">
                  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Student details" collapsible="true" columns="1">
                      <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
                      <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Phone}"/>

                  </apex:pageBlockSection>

                    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                        <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="/apex/New4"/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
             </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

When i click on preview, the correct page will display for one sec and then it will re-direct to blank white page.

Here is the url for blank white page.

Comment: I tried that same page and it is working fine.

Comment: Perhaps the org you're in has overridden the "view" action for Account. Not sure if that could affect previews like this though.